# Can I pass an instance of HttpServletRequest to Facades

Tags: jsp, java-ee-6

If I am using a pattern JSP->Controller->Facade->Services->DAO for my application, is it good or bad practice to pass my instance of HttpServletRequest to my facade. I have my benefits for sending the request, but I am not sure to do it or not.

If this is a bad practice, please explain why you think so, so that I would get a better idea why I shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not good practice. By doing that, you tie your facade to a specific view technology. By doing that you also put presentation-layer logic inside the service layer, which goes against the layer separation that you decided to use. And finally, it would prevent putting the service layer on another JVM than the presentation layer.

You should extract data from the HTTP request inside the controller, transform this data into objects, with the appropriate types, and pass these objects to the service layer. This will also make the service layer more testable.